# Do HTML5 custom elements have any drawbacks compared to classes?

Tags: html

I don't like div soups. You don't easily see which end tag belongs to which start tag (correct indentation helps, I know), yadda yadda. HTML5 introduced custom elements. Is there any drawback using them instead of classes except for browser support, since older Edge and IE don't support them?
I think this this HTML code:

```
<blog-posts>
  <blog-post>
    <blog-title>Do HTML5 custom elements have any drawbacks compared to classes?</blog-title>
    <blog-content>I don't like div soups</blog-content>
  </blog-post>
</blog-posts>
```

is much nicer to read than

```
<div class="blog-posts">
  <div class="blog-posts">
    <div class="blog-title">Do HTML5 custom elements have any drawbacks compared to classes?</div>
    <div>I don't like div soups</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I understood correctly, even if I don't call `document.registerElement` for my custom elements, this will work just fine, since the elements will by default inherit from `HTMLElement`, which gives my more or less the same behavior as the `HTMLDivElement`.

Comment: The jury seems to be out on this question, and it really depends on your use case. The biggest drawback you will likely see is it makes it harder for some applications to divine your intention. A good example of this would be a browser's reading mode, which could have trouble parsing your page if it's using non-standard tags. Beyond that, custom elements are supported and perfectly valid. Another thing to keep in mind is your CSS might become considerably more complex as it's a lot easier to apply styles to all divs rather than having a giant comma-separated selector.

Comment: If your only reason for using custom elements is because it's easier to find the start and end tags, consider using an IDE with code folding, and always remember to properly indent your code.

Comment: _"much nicer to read"_ is only 1% of what Native Web Components (Custom Elements API, templates and shadowDOM) are

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman: I'm aware it's only 1%, that's also one reason for my question: Is it ok to use this mighty tool for almost purely cosmetic reasons? I guess it is, but apparently it's not common to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Always distrust developers who tell you what you should or shouldn't do.

It is your code, if it works for you, it works.

You are using W3C standard technologies so it will work for as long Browsers run JavaScript.

Yes, Web Components V0 (Google threw something against the wall) got a bad reputation;
but we are on V1 now, since 2018, and Google, Apple, Mozilla, Microsoft are now more closely working together.
(WTF.. Where is Facebook?)

Personally, I prefer:

```html
<blog-posts-listing>
  <blog-post title="Do HTML5 custom elements have any drawbacks compared to classes?"> 
    I don't like DIV soups
  </blog-post>
  <blog-post title="What is the future for React?" tags="React">     
    I don't like **JSX** soup either
  </blog-post>
</blog-posts-listing>
```

Because `<blog-post>` would be the work-horse that creates content in shadowDOM from this lightDOM.

Good use of attributes allow for great CSS

```css
blog-post:not([title*="React"]){
  background-color:lightgreen;
}

blog-post[title*="React"]{
  background-color:lightcoral;
}
```

You can even add search with minimal JS, create styles dynamically

Adding functionality like a MarkDown parser is a breeze then

Do not create HTML tags just because you can create HTML tags...

But remember what I said about Developer advice.